# Could not deduce ....context Ord Haskell

Tags: haskell

for learning purposes I am trying to zip 2 lists together , only if the length of both matches. ( Must be the same length ) Unfortunately , it refuses to compile.
I assume there is something wrong with the signature.. Thank you in anticipation.
Here is my Code:

```
ziptogether :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
ziptogether [] [] = 0
ziptogether (x:xs) (y:ys) 
   | length(x:xs) == length(y:ys) = zip (x:xs) (y:xs)
   | otherwise = error "not same length"
```

Error:

```
     Could not deduce (a ~ (a, a))
     from the context (Ord a)
      bound by the type signature for
                ziptogether :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
      at new.hs:2:16-43
         `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
         the type signature for ziptogether :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
         at new.hs:2:16
    Expected type: [a]
     Actual type: [(a, a)]
    In the return type of a call of `zip'
    In the expression: zip (x : xs) (y : xs)
    In an equation for `ziptogether':
    ziptogether (x : xs) (y : ys)
      | length (x : xs) == length (y : ys) = zip (x : xs) (y : xs)
      | otherwise = error "not same length"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems. Your type signature says you take two lists and return another, your first problem is

```
 ziptogether [] [] = 0
```

So this takes to elements and returns.. a number. I think you want

```
 ziptogether [] [] = []
```

The next problem is that you recursively call `zip`, which returns `[(a, a)]`. You can change your type signature to

```
 ziptogether :: [a] -> [a] -> [(a, a)]
 ziptogether [] [] = []
 ziptogether (x:xs) (y:ys) | length xs == length ys = zip (x:xs) (y:ys)
                           | otherwise = error "Not the same length"
```

Of course you can eliminate the extra case here

```
 ziptogether xs ys | length xs == length ys = zip xs ys
                   | otherwise              = error "Not the same length"
```

Notice that we don't need an `Ord` constraint. You only need this if you plan to use operations like `<` or similar.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have one question , why have you neglected "Ord(a)" . Aren't we making a comparison between the 2 lists ? We are comparing the lengths of both. Why is Ord not necessary here ?

Comment: @user2938633 The length of two lists is an `Int`, it doesn't matter what's in the list, it's length is just a number. If we wanted to compare elements, then we'd need to some constraints. But we don't so we don't.

Comment: Okay understood, thanks. Second question.
It compiles now , but it does not make this what it should do..
I changed my code after your corrections and when I type ziptogether [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8] it gives me [(1,1), (2,2) (3,3) , (4,4) ] as a result . Why ?

Comment: @user2938633 I'm afraid I'm unable to replicate this behavior http://ideone.com/xAQmDH

Comment: Oh , what a mistake. Accidentally I wrote zip xs xs instead of zip xs ys. Shame on me ! Nevertheless , thank you very much jozefg. Helped me a lot , again !